# Build React Native to IOS

Tags: android, ios, react-native

I had make a simple app using react native and I want to build it in Ios and Android. I already build and install in android, however, I cannot do that for Ios. Does anyone have commands or complete steps to build react native project into IOS?

Answer (score 0):

- Check pod file first. If it's not there create one using `pod init`.
- Then install pods. (`pod install`)
- Run app using `react-native run-ios` or you can open .workspace file in xcode and build app from there.

Comment: i am using Vsc instead of Xcode. I tried those commands none of them are works.

Comment: Please post the errors for us to see what happened. @jauhar13

Comment: Authentication with Apple Developer Portal failed!
Failed to set up Distribution Certificate
Failed to prepare all credentials. 
The next time you build, we will automatically use the following configuration:
No credentials configured for app @jauh*****/T******-Mobile-App with bundle identifier com.ja*********.Tm

You have no team associated with your Apple account, cannot proceed.
(Do you have a paid Apple Developer account?)

Comment: You don't need paid apple developer account just to build app. But you have to set the team from xcode level. How you create the project btw ?  using react-native init <projectName> or is it Expo app ?

Comment: i used expo to build the app